# VS Add-on to Copy full type name of identifier under the cursor into clipboard

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-extensions

Is there a visual studio add-on to copy the full type name of the identifier under the cursor into clipboard?  Please DO NOT link me to "[VS 2010 - easy way to copy full type name of a class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971997/vs-2010-easy-way-to-copy-full-type-name-of-a-class-interface)" I don't want to deal with macros; only add-ons.  Thanks :)

Comment: You mean you have your cursor in the identifier, you've no selection and hitting Ctrl+C copies the identifier to clipboard?

Comment: No, that would be silly. I'm thinking more of a right click menu item to do it.

Comment: No its not silly. By default, VS 2010 copies the whole line if you don't have any selection. I guess older versions copied word only (although my memory is vague on this). AFAIK, there is no addon/extension that does that as this becomes the non-standard behavior (compared to other IDEs). It should be an easy one to write  though.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566628/is-there-a-way-within-visual-studio-to-easily-get-qualified-type-names

Comment: I asked my question first. :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, Visual Studio's Object Browser gets you what you want. Unfortunately, the task might be cumbersome without Resharper.

If you have Resharper, you can set up a key binding for `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.NavigateTo.Resharper_NavigateToObjectBrowser`

[image: EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.NavigateTo.Resharper_NavigateToObjectBrowser]

To copy the full type name of a property, method, or class to the clipboard, position your cursor in the relevant spot... (for example)

[image]

Now press your new keyboard shortcut (CTRL+ALT-J in my example above).

[image]

Once in the object browser, you can press CTRL+C immediately to copy what you want to the clipboard.

Flip over to any ol' application now and press CTRL+V to paste the contents..

[image]

Comment: Speeking of ReSharper indeed it's faster to press [Alt] + [~], then go straight to "Object browser".

Comment: It's now perhaps just as fast, but easier, to press ALT+ENTER, then begin typing "object browser". ALT+ENTER can do anything now.

Comment: Alex, you mean RS9, I suppose. We're still running on RS8.0 with no upgrade in foreseeable future :(

Comment: Yes, sorry. RS9 introduced the mega ALT+ENTER feature.

Comment: This has been inoperable/broken since we moved to VS2015. I was hoping VS2015 Update 1 would fix it, or the 10.0.1 release of ReSharper, but alas, it is still broken. I have Ctrl+Alt+J mapped properly, as above, but pressing it does nothing. If anyone out there has this working in VS2015, can you chime in? Maybe I just have an errant setting preventing this from working.

Comment: @sliderhouserules This seems to work again.. at least with the current VS 2015 and R# 10 EAP.

Comment: If you have a recent ReSharper version you can use the menu option called **ReSharper/Edit/Copy Fully-qualified name/ Source browser URI to clipboard**.